# Where should I save my files before making the install?

Tags: make

Apologies for the perhaps silly question. Say that I have a tarball that doesn't come with a ./configuration script, if I download the file in the temp Download folder and then I make the make --install, will the file:

a) compiled and moved somewhere so that I can delete the temp folder
b) compiled and linked to the temp folder?

Assuming b), what's the best location to move these applications?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete tarball of source code typically can be unpacked anywhere. In the created folder, the compilation can be performed with normal user rights. The "install" command, which must be run as "root", will install the compiled binaries in the appropriate system locations.

Where and whether you keep the tarball or the extracted tarball is entirely up to you. You can organize this somewhere in your home folder as you see fit or remove them.

Comment: Thanks, so once the file is installed, I can safely delete the downloaded and extracted packages. Correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, also added that you can remove them.

Comment: Do you have any advice for a "portable app". Specifically, I'm trying to see what should I do with the boxcryptor service. Apparently that has not a make install ... but a shell file that run the software from the unzipped file. Where is the best place to place that folder?

Comment: That is a different question. Feel free to find an answer on this site, or, if not avaiable, open a new question.

Comment: You can consider [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). If your application is only for one user you may put the executables into `$HOME/.local/bin`.